# Estimate Gas For Smart Contract Always Fails

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-deployment, web3.py, gas-estimate

I have deployed a very simple contract to the Ethereum blockchain to be able to split a payment across two different outputs.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract MoonTrade
{
    function multiSendETH(  address payable address1,
                            uint value1,
                            address payable address2,
                            uint value2) public payable
    {
        address1.transfer(value1);
        address2.transfer(value2);

        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

It is on the Ropsten testnet.
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x3376a6d3e46496944fe7afd838efb949007b80f4

I am using web3py (python)

However, whenever I try to do `web3.eth.estimateGas()` I always get an error saying:

Gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction (Error code -32000)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is the input I"m passing to estimate gas:

```
{'to': 0x3376a6D3e46496944fe7afD838EfB949007B80f4, 
    'from': 0xF811E7eD1BBc908f33b1C298087220D249bE0464, 
    'value': 50000000000000000, 
    'data': b'{"name": "multiSendETH", "types": ["address","uint256","address","uint256"],"inputs":["0xbe623C1f9F47d2105f80A9A5c0Cd90562be5fA58", "40000000000000000","0x366de12a1A6fd0B140153f011c1A085314A047BC", "10000000000000000"]}'}
```

The data part is obviously converted to bytes using `web3.toBytes()` before being passed into the estimate gas function.

I'm clueless as to if this error is related to my smart contract or the way I am passing the parameters into estimate gas.

Any ideas?

Here is my debug output:

```
ABI: [{"constant": false,"inputs": [{"name": "address1","type": "address"},{"name": "value1","type": "uint256"},{"name": "address2","type": "address"},{"name": "value2","type": "uint256"}],"name": "multiSendETH","outputs": [],"payable": true,"stateMutability": "payable","type": "function"}]

Contract address: 0x60946D10048EC9fbB0A260bb17da2eFEbdb76F12

Estimate gas data: {'to': 0x60946D10048EC9fbB0A260bb17da2eFEbdb76F12, 'from': 0xF811E7eD1BBc908f33b1C298087220D249bE0464, 'value': 50000000000000000, 'data': b'{"name": "multiSendETH", "types": ["address","uint256","address","uint256"],"inputs":["0xbe623C1f9F47d2105f80A9A5c0Cd90562be5fA58", "40000000000000000","0x366de12a1A6fd0B140153f011c1A085314A047BC", "10000000000000000"]}'}

Total gas fee in WEI: 6600000000000000

Gas price in WEI: 22000000000

Transaction data to be used: {"name": "multiSendETH", "types": ["address","uint256","address","uint256"],"inputs":["0xbe623C1f9F47d2105f80A9A5c0Cd90562be5fA58", "33400000000000000","0x366de12a1A6fd0B140153f011c1A085314A047BC", "10000000000000000"]}

Signed transaction: AttrDict({'rawTransaction': HexBytes('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'), 'hash': HexBytes('0x6f4e47b48d1c4e37fc360d97f5e15a05e6100a6058b33442419617c536690e33'), 'r': 84374024802743941308955771074764079224633082170439044639020403769288422643140, 's': 53718021940567424333967254769074396806767762625919492526766162521994190126924, 'v': 27})

Gas: 3E-13

Gas price: 2.2E-8

Value: 0.05

Gas * gasprice + value = 0.0566

{"error":"{'code': -32000, 'message': 'insufficient funds for gas * price + value'}"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with how you are calling estimateGas is that you are passing in invalid transaction which contains an invalid bytecode.

`'data': b'{"name": "multiSendETH", "types": ["address","uint256","address","uint256"],"inputs":["0xbe623C1f9F47d2105f80A9A5c0Cd90562be5fA58", "40000000000000000","0x366de12a1A6fd0B140153f011c1A085314A047BC", "10000000000000000"]}'}`

^ is not correct.

The correct format is something like this:
`0x23b872dd000000000000000000000000bb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413000000000000000000000000713fa27cb26b5902ea398b04d21e6018bba3a2f100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000072ae557d778bd174`

To build the transaction properly for calling smart contract functions, you can refer to https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.ContractFunction.buildTransaction